# Given a line on the surface of a cylinder and a point. What is the closest point on the line.

Tags: geometry

I have

- a cylinder **C**
- a straight line segment $L = L_0 \rightarrow L_1$ on the surface of the cylinder. A helix in 3D
- a point **P** on the surface of the cylinder.
- Note that the equation to the line, in the coordinate system of the cylinder surface is $L = L_0 + \mathbf{v}t$ where $\mathbf{v} = L_1 - L_0$

I wish to find closest point on **L** from **P**.

Note **L** is finite length and can have any orientation and all distances are measured along the surface of the cylinder.

Comment: As  it is a striaght line with the above equation lying on the cylinder, I think this st. line should be parallel to the axis of the cylinder, and thus to find the point Q on L which satifies shortest distance between L and  P, it is enough to find the intersection between the st  line L  and the ring of the cylinder which passes through P  and has axis same as axis of cylinder.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. It is a straight line in the coordinate system of the __surface__ of the cylinder. In 3D it is a helix. I updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: How are you measuring the distance from __P__ to __L__ $-$ along the surface of the cylinder, or in 3-space?

Comment: If you are measuring the distance in 3-space, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13341/1508). It doesn't allow for __L__ being finite, so you will have to modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: All distances are measured along the surface of the cylinder. Updated question to make this clear sorry.